# Crontab function not executing

Tags: pi-3b+

Hell My name is Patrick and a Rpi newbi. I have made this project" industrial strenght cat feeder" from the instructables website. Everything is working 100% aside from the crontab function. Ths crontab is running ( i see the log's)  but not executing the command.
This is the original crontab command :

```
10 */1 * * * sh /var/www/html/camera.sh >> /home/icf/logs/camera 2>&1
0 * * * * sh /home/icf/catFeeder/checkDispenseFood.sh >> /home/icf/logs/cronlog  2>&1
```

The locations and sh names are correct.Timing also.
Then i have read to delete the sh after the crontab *****. So i changed to this:

```
10 */1 * * * /var/www/html/camera.sh >> /home/icf/logs/camera 2>&1
0 * * * * /home/icf/catFeeder/checkDispenseFood.sh >> /home/icf/logs/cronlog  2>&1
```

Same result:.... nothing.

Can anybody give some advice?
Can i manually run the crontab command to test because in the "sh" the time is compared to a setting txt table ( with 3 programmable times per day) every hour on the hour. This also works as i can see the logs for checking the table every hour.

Comment: If you want help you need to explain **What YOU did** and what you hope to achieve. You haven't even provided a link to the the instructables(sic) website (although lots of stuff there is rubbish)

Comment: Thank you very much for the contributing answer.

Comment: Have you looked inside the `/home/icf/logs` folder, and examined the contents of the `camera` and the `cronlog` files? The [project's website](https://www.instructables.com/Industrial-Strength-Cat-pet-Feeder/) has a `**ASK QUESTIONS**` link - did you try that?

Comment: Yes did ask them but no reaction

Comment: even after testing the command as the user whose crontab it is scheduled to, remove any dependencies on something in your environment that are not in the one cron runs (use absolute paths, etc).  also try replacing actual jobs with some simple hello world to see outputs.

Answer (score 2):

**PATH** seems to be the bane of *crontab* users.

As a test do this:

From the command line:

```
echo $PATH
```

Hang on to the results. Now make a crontab entry of:

```
* * * * * source ~/.bashrc; echo $PATH >> ~/crontab_log.txt 2>&1
```

This will make a *crontab.log entry* every minute of the PATH used by crontab. Odds are it will be radically different.

Now go back into your crontab and make an entry **before all others** of:

```
PATH={the same path from your command line echo}
```

Verify the path is shown in the log after the cron runs in a minute.

See if your *catdispenser* program is running from cron.

Consider trimming out unnecessary PATH content from the CRON.

Don't forget to remove the now unnecessary CRONTAB **ECHO**.

Answer (score 0):

I would run through the following checks:

1. Ensure your script is executable, make sure you can run it standalone from the command line /home/icf/catFeeder/checkDispenseFood.sh you may have to use chmod +x to do this. Bear in mind that cron is not running as your userid so the script will need to be executable by cron.
2. Edit your script to include the shell you want to use on the first line of the script e.g. #!/bin/sh or #!/bin/bash or similar.
3. Use a cron editor e.g. https://crontab.guru/ to get the syntax right for the schedule you want. Use crontab -e to edit and update the crontab file.
4. You can test the run by simply putting a line into the crontab that is a minute or two later than the current time and checking it has run
   e.g. 5 * * * * will run at 5 minutes past the hour.

More useful information here https://pimylifeup.com/cron-jobs-and-crontab/

Comment: I would run through the following checks:

   1:  I did and it works this way. ????     2: This line is present in the crontab file.   3: Timing is ok. I used GURU also.    4: timing is working.